# Jhipster - one to many relationship - jsonignore

Tags: jhipster

I have set a one-to-many relationship between two entities. In the owner entity, I see that jhipster generator added a **JsonIgnore** nanotation to the one-to-many property.
If I remove the **JsonIgnore** annotation I am getting this runtime error :

> *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844

Is there a way to fix this error message?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found the solution.

Visit [Collection null in AngularJS + Spring Data JPA @OneToMany @ManyToOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364711/collection-null-in-angularjs-spring-data-jpa-onetomany-manytoone/31070092#31070092)

I hope it helps you