# Collection null in AngularJS + Spring Data JPA @OneToMany @ManyToOne

Tags: angularjs, spring, jpa, jhipster

I have a bidirectional relationship. 
This is my **entity factura**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_FACTURA")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Factura implements Serializable {
   ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "factura")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Facturaservicio> facturaservicios = new HashSet<>();
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //all attributes except facturaservicios
    }
}
```

This is my **entity facturaservicio**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_FACTURASERVICIO")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Facturaservicio implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Factura factura;
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //all attributes except factura
    }
}
```

This is my **REST controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class FacturaResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FacturaResource.class);

    @Inject
    private FacturaRepository facturaRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/facturas",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public List<Factura> getAll() {
        log.debug("REST request to get all Facturas");
        return facturaRepository.findAll();
    }
```

And this is my **AngularJS controller**:

```
 $http.get('app/rest/facturas').
                        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

**Why my collection is null in the AngularJS controller? How can I access to collection?**

Comment: Your using a relative url in your $http.get, is that correct? Are you sure that there is definitely data to be returned? What is the status code?

Comment: @thedoctor I use Postman and it returned a JSON with all attributes excepts my collection. If I print with console.log(), it returned null. I don't have any error

Comment: Have you tried adding a @ResponseBody annotation to your get method?

Comment: I just try it, but it can't work because shows the same

Comment: It could be related to the toString() method?

Comment: No, the toString() is not used in this case. What version of Jackson are you using? I would normally have created a DTO class with JAXB annotations which I use to return data from my API, and then embedded the result array as a field within that.

Comment: jackson_version=2.3.3 and I used JHipster to generate the proyect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When JHipster creates a entity with OneToMany - ManyToOne relationship makes that the first entity (factura) has a list of the second entity (facturaservicios) but it not say the type of relation.

So the **solution** is add **fetch = FetchType.EAGER** in the @OneToManyRelation.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "factura", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Facturaservicio> facturaservicios = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToOne
private Factura factura;
```

Comment: As of the time of this comment, your answer includes the `@JsonIgnore` annotation. Are you sure you did not have to remove this annotation?

Answer (score 0):

In the Factura entity, you need to remove the `@JsonIgnore` property in the following snippet:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "factura")
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Facturaservicio> facturaservicios = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: If I remove @JsonIgnore, it print "facturaservicios":null